# destring dates and times in stata

Tags: database, date, stata

Variable: report_date_time

```
       11/8/2005 12:00:00 AM
```

How to destring this variable into a date variable  with Stata?
I do not need the time (12:00:00 AM) and need to keep the dates only (11/8/2005).

Comment: Please do some research and make an attempt. If you have issues post your code and someone will help. This isn't a code writing service.

Comment: Dates in Stata can be daily, weekly, monthly, quarterly, half-yearly or yearly. Your intent is clear in this case, but for communication and for looking at the documentation it's helpful to be explicit about the kind of date you want, namely _daily_ dates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The starting point is reading `help datetime` and the linked-to section `help datetime translation`. Assuming your sample date is month-day-year order (and not day-month-year), the following example demonstrates the key concepts. The use of "#" in the `mask` argument to `daily()` (which is a more expressive name for the `date()` function) tells it to ignore the stuff after the year; without that a missing value is the result.

```
clear
input str30 date_s 
"11/8/2005 12:00:00 AM"
end
generate newdate = daily(date_s,"MDY#")
format newdate %td
list, clean
```

And the output is

```
                      date_s     newdate  
  1.   11/8/2005 12:00:00 AM   08nov2005
```